# Changing Rotation Angle Using Align Euler to Vector Node

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

I have a vector `V = (x, y, z)` and I need to rotate an object in the direction of this vector. I can do that by calculating the rotation `R` using **Align Euler to Vector** node. But if I further want to rotate the same object along the same direction by `theta` radians, what's the way to do that?

I tried adding / multiplying `theta` to the original Vector `V` as well as the resulting Rotation `R`; that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplying an Euler rotation won't extrapolate the rotation in the way you want, because Euler rotations are sets of 3 rotations done in a sequence, so rotating by a multiplied Euler will stack first x rotations, then y rotations, then z rotations…

[image]

But instead of stacking it this way:

```
xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzz
```

You want to stack it this way:

```
xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
```

[image]

For a smooth animation you could take a cross product, and rotate around the custom axis:

[image]

Fine, but what if you don't know the angle to reach the target and want to operate on multiples of that? for example what if you want to extrapolate only up to a factor of $3$, which means a 3 times more rotation than the one needed to point at the target? Speaking of the *factor* - this input socket is interesting:

[image]

If only there was a way to go outside $[0, 1]$ range to extrapolate…

[image]

Answer (score 4):

i am not sure whether this is what you want, but the align euler to vector node calculates an absolute value as rotation for a direction. So if you really wanna make an animation out of this, e.g. rotate from +z to -z via +y, you could use a node tree like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Here i first animate the direction/rotation change from +z to +y via the first mix node. Then i animate the direction/rotation change from +y to -z via the second mix node.

So you basically animate the direction vectors and change these over time to get the rotation.

There might be other/better ways, but that's one way i know.